# Woocommerce: Remove item from cart hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, filter, hook

I have following hook which is working fine, it does add the remove icon in checkout page to allow remove item from cart. However it does hide the product name in cart page. How to make it work only in checkout page but not the cart, or how to stop this hook from hiding product name in cart page ?

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link', 10, 3);

function njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key)
{
if (is_checkout()) {
        $product_name .= apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove" style="float:left;">&times;</a>',
        esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
        esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
        esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
        ), $cart_item_key);

        return $product_name;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using filter you must return.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link', 10, 3);

function njengah_filter_wc_cart_item_remove_link($product_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key){
    if (is_checkout()) {
        $product_name .= apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link', sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" class="remove" style="float:left;">&times;</a>',
        esc_url(wc_get_cart_remove_url($cart_item_key)),
        __('Remove this item', 'woocommerce'),
        esc_attr($cart_item['product_id']),
        esc_attr($cart_item['data']->get_sku())
        ), $cart_item_key);
    }
    return $product_name;
}
```

Comment: wow! small mistake, thank you for quick response.

Comment: Welcome... glad to be of help.